# Postgresql stored procedure execute error

Tags: postgresql

I created a stored procedure. The function is created successfully. When I call function I get an error. How can I solve this problem?

The error is

> ERROR:  unrecognized conversion type specifier "a"
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dwgcould.updatescale(integer,integer) line 6 at EXECUTE statement
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERROR: unrecognized conversion type specifier "a"
>   SQL state: 22023
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function dwgcould.updatescale(integer,integer) line 6 at EXECUTE statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scale(IN id integer, IN scale integer) RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE 
    result int;
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_tables where tablename = format('table_%s_id',id)) > 0 then
    EXECUTE format('update table_%s_id  set geom = ST_Scale(geom, %a, %a',id, scale, scale) using id, scale;
    EXECUTE format('update table_&s_id2  set geom = ST_Scale(geom, %a, %a',id, scale, scale) using id, scale;
    IF FOUND THEN 
        result:= 1;
        return result;
    ELSE 
        result:=0;
        return result;
    END IF; 
  ELSE 
    result:=2;
    return result;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You should use `%s`.

Comment: `How can I solve this problem?` By not using a `%a` specifier.

Comment: `ST_Scale(geom,%a,%a` - no closing bracket

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `result` variable is useless. You can simply do `return 1;`  or `return 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix up the use of positional parameters in `format()` and variables for substitution in the `EXECUTE` command:

```
 EXECUTE format('update table_%s_id set geom = ST_Scale(geom, %s, %s)', id, scale, scale);
```

If you want to return a `row_id`from the `EXECUTE command, the you should explicitly specify that in the UPDATE query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scale(id integer, scale integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE 
    result integer;
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = format('table_%s_id',id)) > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE table_%s_id SET geom = ST_Scale(geom, %s, %s)', id, scale, scale) using id, scale;
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE table_&s_id2 SET geom = ST_Scale(geom, %s, %s)
                    RETURNING row_id',id, scale, scale) INTO result;
    RETURN result;
  END IF;
  RETURN 2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working. But when I use directly query for example update table_10_10 set geom = ST_Scale(geom, 150, 150). updated rows is 346 but result is returning 0.

Comment: I dont' have row_id so I get an error. I just want to do if query is done return 1 else return 0. I think execute format doesnt work

Comment: @Faith in your Question, you used `FOUND`.  I would think that would work, but also see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS - you can also use `GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT;`